# Scaleable to camera 3d line on an android device

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, line

I need to draw a growing 3d line using open gl on an Android device.

The problem is I need to draw lines that scale with a "laser" type effect on them.

Originally I just thought of drawing simple gl lines or line loops but they wont scale if the camera is moved closer to them - like a fly through.

My next thought was to generate a cylinder mesh and extrude it as I would do a line in real time, accounting for 90 degree turns by adding a 45degree rotation after extruding from the end point a new cylinder, turning the end 45degrees again and extruding another cylinder to create the new line extension and so on and so-forth...

Problem with cylinders is the near clipping plane will clip through them.

Anyone have a better thought or idea they can throw at me for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Problem with cylinders is the near clipping plane will clip through them.

This will be the case with any kind of geometry. You can however use depth clamping to avoid some of the effects of clipping. See here for details http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tut05%20Depth%20Clamping.html

Comment: Thanks, I've considered it, but it still does allow a portion.  I think I'm going to just have to use the "extruded cylinder" method and render it in a way that the clipping will not be an issue via texture & blend.

Comment: You could also try axial billboards.